# C# ASP.NET JSON to a JSON array Cannot deserialize the current JSON object

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I'm using Json.Net to DeserializeObject Json data into object/collection (list)

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and I have tried this:

```
        public List<RootObject> GetRecipes()
    {
        string summonerID = Session["summonerID"].ToString();
        string downloadedString;
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        downloadedString = client.DownloadString("https://tr.api.pvp.net/api/lol/tr/v1.3/game/by-summoner/" + summonerID + "/recent?api_key=55686aef-da52-4184-b987-98799662d92e"); //tırnak içerisine istediğiniz web adresini yazınız
        List<RootObject> liste = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(@downloadedString);
        return liste;
        lblYazi.Text = liste.ToString();
    }
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[KYLOL2.WebForm2+RootObject]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
```

To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'summonerId', line 1, position 14.

[My Json link](https://tr.api.pvp.net/api/lol/tr/v1.3/game/by-summoner/9093591/recent?api_key=55686aef-da52-4184-b987-98799662d92e)

My Class

```
public class FellowPlayer
    {
        public int summonerId { get; set; }
        public int teamId { get; set; }
        public int championId { get; set; }
    }

    public class Stats
    {
        public int level { get; set; }
        public int goldEarned { get; set; }
        public int numDeaths { get; set; }
        public int minionsKilled { get; set; }
        public int championsKilled { get; set; }
        public int goldSpent { get; set; }
        public int totalDamageDealt { get; set; }
        public int totalDamageTaken { get; set; }
        public int doubleKills { get; set; }
        public int killingSprees { get; set; }
        public int largestKillingSpree { get; set; }
        public int team { get; set; }
        public bool win { get; set; }
        public int neutralMinionsKilled { get; set; }
        public int largestMultiKill { get; set; }
        public int physicalDamageDealtPlayer { get; set; }
        public int magicDamageDealtPlayer { get; set; }
        public int physicalDamageTaken { get; set; }
        public int magicDamageTaken { get; set; }
        public int largestCriticalStrike { get; set; }
        public int timePlayed { get; set; }
        public int totalHeal { get; set; }
        public int totalUnitsHealed { get; set; }
        public int assists { get; set; }
        public int item0 { get; set; }
        public int item1 { get; set; }
        public int item2 { get; set; }
        public int item3 { get; set; }
        public int item4 { get; set; }
        public int item6 { get; set; }
        public int magicDamageDealtToChampions { get; set; }
        public int physicalDamageDealtToChampions { get; set; }
        public int totalDamageDealtToChampions { get; set; }
        public int trueDamageTaken { get; set; }
        public int neutralMinionsKilledEnemyJungle { get; set; }
        public int totalTimeCrowdControlDealt { get; set; }
        public int playerRole { get; set; }
        public int playerPosition { get; set; }
        public int? turretsKilled { get; set; }
        public int? item5 { get; set; }
        public int? wardPlaced { get; set; }
        public int? neutralMinionsKilledYourJungle { get; set; }
        public int? trueDamageDealtPlayer { get; set; }
        public int? trueDamageDealtToChampions { get; set; }
        public int? bountyLevel { get; set; }
        public int? tripleKills { get; set; }
        public int? wardKilled { get; set; }
        public int? barracksKilled { get; set; }
    }

    public class Game
    {
        public int gameId { get; set; }
        public bool invalid { get; set; }
        public string gameMode { get; set; }
        public string gameType { get; set; }
        public string subType { get; set; }
        public int mapId { get; set; }
        public int teamId { get; set; }
        public int championId { get; set; }
        public int spell1 { get; set; }
        public int spell2 { get; set; }
        public int level { get; set; }
        public int ipEarned { get; set; }
        public object createDate { get; set; }
        public List<FellowPlayer> fellowPlayers { get; set; }
        public Stats stats { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public int summonerId { get; set; }
        public List<Game> games { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are telling the deserializer to look for RootObject as a List, but it's not in the example you are providing.  Something like this should work better:

```
RootObject liste = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(@downloadedString);
```

So something like this:

```
public RootObject GetRecipes()
{
    string summonerID = Session["summonerID"].ToString();
    string downloadedString;
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    downloadedString = client.DownloadString("https://tr.api.pvp.net/api/lol/tr/v1.3/game/by-summoner/" + summonerID + "/recent?api_key=55686aef-da52-4184-b987-98799662d92e"); //tırnak içerisine istediğiniz web adresini yazınız
    RootObject liste = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(@downloadedString);
    return liste;
    lblYazi.Text = liste.ToString();  // never reaches this code
}
```

or if you need to keep the prototype of the GetRecipes method:

```
public List<RootObject> GetRecipes()
{
    string summonerID = Session["summonerID"].ToString();
    string downloadedString;
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    downloadedString = client.DownloadString("https://tr.api.pvp.net/api/lol/tr/v1.3/game/by-summoner/" + summonerID + "/recent?api_key=55686aef-da52-4184-b987-98799662d92e"); //tırnak içerisine istediğiniz web adresini yazınız
    List<RootObject> liste = new List<RootObject>();  // create the return list
    RootObject e = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(@downloadedString);
    liste.Add(e);  // add the reserialized object to the list we are returning
    return liste;
    lblYazi.Text = liste.ToString();  // never reaches this code
}
```

Comment: hello I did that well, but gave the following error

Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'KYLOL2.WebForm2.RootObject' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<KYLOL2.WebForm2.RootObject>' C:\Users\yunus2\KYLOL2\KYLOL2\maclar.aspx.cs 116 20 KYLOL2

Comment: method needs to change a little if you do that.  I will edit answer with a complete example.

Comment: Hello, how can I write a text or tables that list